# How can I implement a background RSS reader in iOS?

Tags: ios, xml, background, rss

I need to implement an RSS reader on iOS which updates its feed every # minutes, even if the app is in the background. I don't mind using NSXMLParser to do the parsing of the data, I just need a good way to do the following in the background at scheduled intervals:

- Download the feed's XML document
- Parse the document
- Let the user know of any updates

I know how to do all of these things when the app is running, I just need to know how to make sure they get done even if the app is in the background.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Apple has strict rules about which apps are allowed to execute in the background. Your app, unfortunately, does not fit any of these categories.

- **audio** — The app plays audible content to the user while in the background. (This content includes streaming audio or video content using AirPlay.)
- **location** — The app keeps users informed of their location, even while it is running in the background.
- **voip** — The app provides the ability for the user to make phone calls using an Internet connection.
- **newsstand-content** — The app is a Newsstand app that downloads and processes magazine or newspaper content in the background.
- **external-accessory** — The app works with a hardware accessory that needs to deliver updates on a regular schedule through the External Accessory framework.
- **bluetooth-central**

From the Apple Docs: [[Source]](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/DOCUMENTATION/iPhone/Conceptual/iPhoneOSProgrammingGuide/ManagingYourApplicationsFlow/ManagingYourApplicationsFlow.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007072-CH4-SW24)

Comment: There's no way to schedule certain limited operations to run in the background?

Comment: No. You can get an extra 10 minutes or so after the user closes the app.

Comment: What about NSBlockOperation or NSOperationQueue?

Comment: No. While you can certainly implement those to help your app, they won't magically make you app circumvent the rules.